# What does buffered, cached, free, slab and used mean when monitoring memory use on GKE?

Tags: memory, kubernetes, memory-usage, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running some compute nodes on GKE and when I look on their memory usage in metrics explorer I see:

[image]

It is clear to me what `used` and `free` mean. But how about the other states?

The official documentation is [quite terse](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent#agent-memory) on the subject.

Comment: https://linuxatemyram.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is standard terminology of Linux Kernel management:

`buffered` - Block device (e.g. harddisk) cache

`cached` - Parked file data (file content) cache

`slab` - Memory used by the kernel to cache data structures for its own use (caches like inode, dentry, etc)